# Equivalent statements regarding combinatorial designs

Tags: combinatorics, matrices, combinatorial-designs

Assume that $2\leq k <v$ and $\lambda>0$ and let $S=\{1,2,...,v\}$. We know that $A_1,A_2,...,A_b$ are subsets of $S$ for which $|A_i|=k,\; \forall i$.  Prove that if any two of the three conditions hold then the third one also holds and the sets $A_1,A_2, . . . , A_b$ form a $(v, k, λ)$-design:

(i) $\displaystyle b=\frac{ λv(v − 1)}{k(k − 1)}$

(ii) Every subset of size $2$ of the set $S$ is included in the set $B_i$ for at least $λ$ indices $i$.

(iii) Every subset of size $2$ of the set $S$ is included in the set $B_i$ for at most $λ$ indices $i$.

My attempts: If (ii) and (iii) hold, the sets by definition of a 2-design form a $(v,k,\lambda)$-design. Then we know that the basic equations $r(k-1)=\lambda(v-1)$ and $bk=vr$ hold so it is easy to solve for $b=\frac{ λv(v − 1)}{k(k − 1)}$.

Then to prove the other 2 cases, I defined a matrix $\boldsymbol{M}_{\binom{v}{2}\times b}$ such that we name the rows as all the subsets (of size 2) of the set $S$ and that the place $t$ on the row corresponding to the subset $\{i,j\}$ is $1$, if ${i, j} \subseteq B_t$ and zero otherwise. I want to first show that the number of $1$'s in the matrix is $b\binom{k}{2}$. I don't know how to finish the arguments so can someone do that or prove these some other way?

Comment: Hint for counting the number of ones in the matrix: how many columns are in the matrix? How many ones are in each column? To answer the latter, you must answer: "how many $2$-element subsets does $A_i$ have?"

Comment: Once you have proven the number of ones is $b\binom{k}2$, you can use $(ii)$ to show the number of ones is at least $\lambda \binom{v}2$ by considering the number of ones in each row of the matrix, which by $(i)$ is equal to $b\binom{k}2$, the total number of ones. This further implies that every row of the matrix has _exactly_ $\lambda$ ones, otherwise the same logic would imply there are more than $b\binom{k}2$ ones in the matrix, a contradiction.